# How to access a method from onCreate of an activity without getting a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to set an alarm when the activity is created but i'm getting a null pointer exception. However it works well when i set the alarm via button click.

So i tried alot of things including setting the method on a different thread inside onCreate() method of the activity but still getting  a NPE.

I also tried setting the onCreate method of my activity public but still same result. Any suggestions maybe?

logcat:

```js
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.snapttechtechnologies.stevekamau.wehappening/com.snapttechtechnologies.stevekamau.wehappening.activities.AddEvent}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at com.snapttechtechnologies.stevekamau.wehappening.helper.ScheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(ScheduleClient.java:60)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at com.snapttechtechnologies.stevekamau.wehappening.activities.AddEvent.setAlarmTime(AddEvent.java:54)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at com.snapttechtechnologies.stevekamau.wehappening.activities.AddEvent.onCreate(AddEvent.java:38)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
11-08 13:51:17.109: E/AndroidRuntime(26046):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
```

AddEvent.java

```js
public class AddEvent extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ScheduleClient scheduleClient;
    // This is the date picker used to select the date for our notification
    private DatePicker picker;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_wehappened);
        // Create a new service client and bind our activity to this service
        scheduleClient = new ScheduleClient(this);
        scheduleClient.doBindService();

      
        setAlarmTime();
    }

    public void setAlarmTime() {
        String input = "Sun Nov 08 2015 13:38";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -60);
        // Ask our service to set an alarm for that date, this activity talks to the client that talks to the service
        scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(cal);
        // Notify the user what they just did
        Toast.makeText(this, "Notification set for: " + cal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    /**
     * This is the onClick called from the XML to set a new notification
     */
    public void onDateSelectedButtonClick(View v) {
        String input = "Sun Nov 08 2015 13:38";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -60);
        // Ask our service to set an alarm for that date, this activity talks to the client that talks to the service
        scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(cal);
        // Notify the user what they just did
        Toast.makeText(this, "Notification set for: " + cal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // When our activity is stopped ensure we also stop the connection to the service
        // this stops us leaking our activity into the system *bad*
        if (scheduleClient != null)
            scheduleClient.doUnbindService();
        super.onStop();
    }
```

ScheduleClient.java

```js
/**
 * This is our service client, it is the 'middle-man' between the
 * service and any activity that wants to connect to the service
 *
 * @author paul.blundell
 */
public class ScheduleClient {

    // The hook into our service
    private ScheduleService mBoundService;
    // The context to start the service in
    private Context mContext;
    // A flag if we are connected to the service or not
    private boolean mIsBound;
    /**
     * When you attempt to connect to the service, this connection will be called with the result.
     * If we have successfully connected we instantiate our service object so that we can call methods on it.
     */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // This is called when the connection with our service has been established,
            // giving us the service object we can use to interact with our service.
            mBoundService = ((ScheduleService.ServiceBinder) service).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mBoundService = null;
        }
    };

    public ScheduleClient(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Call this to connect your activity to your service
     */
    public void doBindService() {
        // Establish a connection with our service
        mContext.bindService(new Intent(mContext, ScheduleService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    /**
     * Tell our service to set an alarm for the given date
     *
     * @param c a date to set the notification for
     */
    public void setAlarmForNotification(Calendar c) {
        mBoundService.setAlarm(c);
    }

    /**
     * When you have finished with the service call this method to stop it
     * releasing your connection and resources
     */
    public void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            mContext.unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code of what you tried mate?

Comment: Problem is not in accessing the method from onCreate, but in what that method does. Obviously something is not initialized, but what we cannot tell without your code and logcat.

Comment: Posting code and logcat right away

Answer (score 1):

Binding services is not synchronous. You're calling a service method immediately after requesting to bind the service connection, and the binding has not been completed yet.

You can use the `onServiceConnected()` callback on your `ServiceConnection` to know when the service has been bound.

Comment: I guessed as much..so I added a thread handler to delay for 3 seconds. Same result.

Comment: If you're blocking the main thread with e.g. `Thread.sleep()` it won't help the binding to occur on the same thread.

Comment: But if I'm understanding you correctly.. You are suggesting I move my code for setting alarm to the ScheduleClient when the connection has been established?